# Is this proof by contraposition of the implication of the disjunkt union correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that $X \dot\cup Y \implies X \cap Y = \emptyset$ by way of contraposition and would like to know if the following suffices as a proof:

1$$\lnot(X \cap Y = \emptyset) = X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$$
2$$\implies \exists x: x \in X \land x \in Y $$
3$$\implies x \in X \lor x \in Y \neq X \dot\cup Y$$

The two things I'm not totally sure of are firstly the implication from $\land$ to $\lor$ in step no. 3 and secondly if it's necessary to use the existential quantifier. I would also really appreciate it if someone were to tell me how a direct proof would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, as you wished, I, the only person who replied to your problem, deleted my answer.   Should I also follow your rude example and down vote your post?

Comment: @WilliamElliot you can do so if you wish. Please note that I downvoted your answer because I didn't find it helpful and wasn't really answering my question, in line to another answer to another question of mine. Also note that I didn't wish for you to delete your answer so much that I didn't find acceptable to start off your answer the way you did.